# Why Ajax AdCall is overriding the html content?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I am using JQuery to invoke a jsp page using Ajax. It works fine when I put just a DateTime in the JSP and the Ajax call is able to show the content of this JSP i.e. DateTime but when I put the Ad code inside the same JSP which was displaying DateTime, I get a page which just only displays the Ad and rest of the content goes away.

I want the Ad to be displayed at a specific location of the page using an Ajax call if the user changes the certain field from a page e.g. the price.

Below is my requirement:
PageA.jsp ---> Ajax call is invoked if the user changes the price inside a text box from PageA.jsp page using JQUery or any JavaScript Framework---> AdCall.jsp page is loaded at a certain div at page PageA.jsp.

Below is the code I am using:

```
   function makeAnAdCall(field) {

  $.ajax({
        url : "AdCall.jsp",
        success : function (data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the area where I am displaying the Ad:

```
<div id="content" style="color:blue;font:bold 14px arial;padding-top:140px;"> Here!
        </div>
```

One of the reason why it is showing just an ad could be because the ad is trying to write the full document write object instead of just writing the specific area. But I am sure there got to be work around for it :) Any suggestion?

Comment: `document.write()` after DOMContentLoaded will overwrite your page. Simply don't use `document.write()` after DOMContentLoaded. What you are doing sounds like something that would be considered against the TOS of several ad-serving networks, make sure you aren't breaking any rules with the particular network you are using. It may also be worthwile to see if said network has an ajax alternative.

Comment: *"I am not using document.write() in the code"* right, but doesn't `adCall.jsp` include javascript that uses `document.write()`

Comment: What you are doing could(will) result in invalid impressions which is against the [TOS](https://www.google.com/intl/en_US/dfp/info/sb/terms.html#utm_source=dfp_sb_fe&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=in-product_link) for doubleclick.

Comment: Correct, the javaScript in the adCall.jsp might have document.write(), unfortunately thats how the ads are being configured. I was just looking to see if there is a workaround even without changing the way ads are configured/served. Because I cannot make a case to change the Ad configuration just for this page. One of the option might be to use IFrame, but not sure if that's the right approach.

Comment: IFramed ads will also generate invalid impressions.

Comment: in place of document.write, what could be the format of javaScript? I can try asking the Ad server folks to send me a specific format specifically for this page.

Comment: Ideally, you would want something similar to `document.getElementById("targetelementid").innerHTML = "thecontent";`

Comment: I was able to set up the ad call and now it gives me the data in this format `<script type="text/javascript">
window.dfptime = window.dfptime || new Date().getTime();
 document.getElementById('content').innerHTML=('<scr'+'ipt language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.doubleclick.net;sz=300x250;lang=en;u=300x250||test|||||en||;tile=1;ord='+window.dfptime+'?"></scr'+'ipt>');
</script>` Now I don't know how should I execute this in the page. My question is how should I load the content instead of calling `$("#content").html(data);` this piece of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using the [writeCapture](https://github.com/iamnoah/writeCapture/wiki/Usage) JavaScript framework. The framework has plugin for JQuery but it can be used without JQuery as well. The only change you have to do is instead of calling the JQuery `$("#content").html(data);` use `$('#content').writeCapture().html(data);`